# My label disappears when my WebBrowser.Document.Title updates. (C#)

Tags: c#

I want to display the current page-name that's on my WebBrowser control on my Label, but when the Document.Title updates, my label disappears instead of showing the current website title. How can i fix this?

```
public partial class StreamViewer : Form
{
    public StreamViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowserViewer.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(webBrowserViewer_DocumentTitleChanged);
    }

    private void webBrowserViewer_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = webBrowserViewer.DocumentTitle;
    }
```

Comment: use the DocumentTitleChanged event

Comment: It is good practice to use Invoke method in other threads. Like label.Invoke(new Action(() => label2.Text = "...";));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DocumentTitleChanged event

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webBrowserViewer.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(webBrowserViewer_DocumentTitleChanged);
}

private void webBrowserViewer_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     label2.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttitlechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: when do you expect the title to change, when you change pages right?

Comment: that event triggers when the document title changes, so you should be getting the latest document title, can you set a break point to see if its being triggered

Comment: yes of course, you need to attach the handler in the form constructor method webBrowserViewer.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(webBrowserViewer_DocumentTitleChanged);

Comment: see my updated answer, you can attach the handler in after init components

Comment: Remove any references to the old DocumentCompleted method, go to the InitializeComponent() method and remove from the this.webBrowserViewer.DocumentCompleted line

Comment: where is your label, it may being covered by the browser, change the label2.text to this.Text, this will show the title change in the form window title, you can see it changing

Comment: also it may be that the page you load has no title text

Comment: yes i can see your label change from 'now playing' to nothing, im pretty sure that the page has no title text, you can set a break point and see what the document title is, if the document title is empty you can use some other info to place there instead

Comment: Hover over DocumentTitle

Comment: so is the label being set with that title within the handler, maybe its got empty spaces to the left of it, and if the label isnt long enough you wont see the rest

Comment: change to webBrowserViewer.DocumentTitle.Trim(); and make your label longer

Comment: can you show me your break point with you hovering DocumentTitle to see the value

Comment: yes this shows that the page has changed and it doesn't have a document title, go to the page in your own browser (chrome etc), what do you see in the window title

Comment: navigate to google.com and see what happend, does it the label change, the whole thing works in my sample app

Comment: maybe the page is changing its title after page load, can you give me the link, i can try myself

Comment: its working fine on my one http://imgur.com/TNwq4QC and code http://imgur.com/VsEdUAP

Comment: can you please upvote and accept answer, i will help you resolve the issues

Comment: yes i can see now, that page has no page title, you can view the source code for it

Comment: you can get the title from the previous page, and then in the handler only set the label if the documenttitle is not empty

Comment: can you delete all our previous comments this list is getting big

Comment: that code uses a regex to extract the name from the page, you can find the relavant text to display, and extract it to display, becuase the page doesnt have a page title